# PopupMenu en Fragment Android

Tags: android, recyclerview, fragment, popup

Tengo un dos proyectos:

- En uno abro en una actividad un `reciclerview` que cargo con `cardviews`, estos cardviews tienen un botón que abre un popupmenu, todo perfecto.
- En el otro proyecto intento hacer lo mismo pero dentro de un `fragment` y me da un error en `popupmenu.show()`= null object pointer.

El código es exactamente el mismo por lo que deduzco que con un fragment funciona diferente.

Lo cargo en un adaptador, por lo que la referencia está en holder.
NOTA: el popup no es nulo, de ahi el Log  (para comprobar), me muestra la referencia del menú.

Yo interpreto que el fallo es que no sabe donde o como hacer el show().

AYUDA!!

```
holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
        }
    });
}


private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
    Log.i("POP",popup.toString());
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: Mira este hilo que es muy similar a lo que preguntas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461990/pop-up-window-to-display-some-stuff-in-a-fragment

Comment: Pon un poco mas del error   unas lineas de cuando explota ok
No se te muestra asi exactamente`popupmenu.show()= null object pointer.`